# jQuery onClick remove class and remove ".click()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I press `a` with class `.home`, javascript removes class `.home`. When I again click on `a` without class `.home`, the javascript still runs. Why?

```
$(".home").click(function(){
    $(".overlay2").fadeIn("medium");
    $(".background").cycle("pause");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".overlay2").fadeOut(500);
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".background").slideUp(800);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".navigation").animate({"top":"20px","left":"20px","margin-top":"0px","margin-left":"0px"},500);
            }, 800);
        }, 500);

    }, 500);
    $(".home").removeClass("home");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have remove the class but the click event handler will still be attached to the elements. You need to use [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`off()`](http://api.jquery.com/off/) to add and remove the handler:

```
;(function() {

    function homeClick() {
        $(".overlay2").fadeIn("medium");
        $(".background").cycle("pause");
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".overlay2").fadeOut(500);
            $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".background").slideUp(800);
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $(".navigation").animate({"top":"20px","left":"20px","margin-top":"0px","margin-left":"0px"},500);
                }, 800);
            }, 500);

        }, 500);

        // remove just the click event for this element ...
        $(this).off('click', homeClick);
        // ... or all .home elements
        $('.home').off('click', homeClick);
    }

    $(".home").on('click', homeClick);

})();
```

Alternatively you can use [`one()`](http://api.jquery.com/one/) so the event only fires once:

```
$(".home").one('click', function(){
    $(".overlay2").fadeIn("medium");
    $(".background").cycle("pause");
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".overlay2").fadeOut(500);
        $(".overlay").fadeOut(500);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(".background").slideUp(800);
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(".navigation").animate({"top":"20px","left":"20px","margin-top":"0px","margin-left":"0px"},500);
            }, 800);
        }, 500);

    }, 500);
    $(this).removeClass("home");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try using the following:

```
$( "a" ).removeClass( "home" );
```

To remove the `class` home from all `a`'s

To remove the `class` home from the `a` on which you've clicked use:

```
$( this ).removeClass( "home" );
```

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR

instead of removeClass, do this:

> $('.home').off('click')

The event handler (the "function" part after "click") is still attached to the DOM element (the actual element that originally had the class .home)

This is what happens:
$('.home') creates a jQuery object of the all elements that match ".home", creates an event listener and attaches a handler (the function) to that listener. As long as you don't replace or remove the elements, all event listeners are still working on those elements, and running those functions. You don't need to remove the class, you just need to turn off (remove) the event listener.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use event delegation because you are dynamically changing the DOM:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function() {
  $(this).removeClass('test');
  alert('clicked');
});
```

```css
.test {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="test">test</span>
```

If you want to achieve on time click without removing classes you can use `one()` like this:

```
$(document).one('click', '.test', function() {  
     // this will get executed only once
});
```